# search query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

when ever we search on google like we search alphabet f then related to this alphabet many sentences or word appear in search like food,foot,etc etc

now i want to store procedure like this
and try this sp

here is sp which i try

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[serchmem]
@MemberID int,
 @Name  nvarchar(50),
@FatherName nvarchar(50),
@NIC nvarchar(50)
as
select * from [mem]
where [Name] like @Name +'[textboxofsearch]%'
```

but it shows me error

ERROR

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
```

Comment: What are your parameters for, and what are you setting them to?

Comment: Only thing I can see is that you might be passing a `varchar` into `@MemberID` rather than an `int`?

Comment: How do you execute your query?

Comment: Not related to your error, but your query should use the @Name parameter passed to the stored procedure.  It's up to your application code to convert textboxsearch to a parameter.

Comment: @tanner in table memberid is in int

Comment: ok i set query like see my update question

Comment: but it alawys show me same error

Comment: ok i done this by using and it worrks for me ....ALTER procedure [dbo].[serchmem]

@Name  nvarchar(50)

as

select * from [mem]
where [Name] like @Name+'%'